# Linux script bash | how to paste in one line

Tags: linux

I have some text file that looks like:

```
k-opp- -l fi -s linux -a BHHHHH7 -d 22.22.222.22 -g ai
k-opp- -l fi -s linux -a BHHHHH8 -d 222.22.22.22 -g ai
k-opp- -l fi -s linux -a BHHHHH9 -d 222.222.22.222 -g ai
```

and I have some script I made:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=list.txt
while read line
do
  echo $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)' >>somefile.txt
  $line <checkcon.sh >>somefile.txt
done < "$file"
```

this script `ssh`es to my machines and runs a second script and takes some info that I need.

The **problem** that the output looks like:

```
BHHHHH7 
eth:    inet 22.22.222.22
BHHHHH8 
eth:    inet 222.22.22.22
BHHHHH8 
eth:    inet 222.222.22.222
```

what I want to do this :

```
BHHHHH7 eth:    inet 22.22.222.22
BHHHHH8 eth:    inet 222.22.22.22
...continues..
```

Anybody know how I can make my script print in one line.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This looks very basic and abstruse at the same time. I am not sure what you want to do with ssh, apart from obtaining some pretty printed output in the end... So, question: is your first block of data `k-opp- -l fi -s linux -a BHHHHH7 -d 22.22.222.22 -g ai[EOL]k-opp- -l fi -s linux -a BHHHHH8 -d 222.22.22.22 -g ai[EOL]...` in one file ?

Comment: ignore the ssh part, the text file is fictive in the real text file  there is links which looks very similar to the presented example with real ip's. The script in the example above, loops on each link from text file ,connect to remote machine and run second script you can see him (checkccon.sh) the second script (checkcon.sh) runs on the remote machine and gives me some info: (eth: inet 22.22.22.....) , what I need to do is to print this info in one line to the new text file .the one line should be like:BHHHHH7 eth: inet 22.22.222.22 the script in the example do it but with 2 lines

Comment: in other words the script ssh to remote machines (in a loop) and collecting for me the ip's of the machines and more, I'm creating a record of all ip's of my remote machines

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution:

```
echo "$(echo $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)' ) $(echo abc)" >> some_file_to_append_next_line_to
```

You will have to change the 2nd part, I changed it so it could be tested, without having to run the command from the data.

The basic form is:

```
command4 "$(command1) $(command2)" "$(command3)"
```

Here `command1` and `command2` are run. Their standard outputs are concatenated together (with a space, as there is one between them). The result is put in argument 1 of `commond4`. The standard out of `command3` is used as argument 2 of `command4`. Then `command4` is executed.

If `command4` is `echo`, then the arguments are concatenated with a space between them, and sent to standard out.

P.S. be careful running command from data, it can leave you open to attack. Any one that provides the data, can run any command that they wish.

Comment: echo "$(echo $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)' )" "$(echo $line<checkcon.sh)" >> somefile.txt

that doesnot work for me

Comment: You have not said what does not work. However I notice that you have added an extra `echo` before `$line`. I used it as a substitute for your command. It should not be used as well as your command.

Comment: I have removed the extra echo
the output is:
eth: inet 222.22.22.22#
 eth: inet 222.22.22.22#
 eth: inet 222.22.22.22#
does not print the first part

Comment: I can't see what is wrong (but then I can't see anything: your code, your input, your output). Have you tried experimenting? I would start with something simple, then build it up.

Comment: Hey man thanks for help , but still have not find the answer. 
I run this command :"echo "$(echo $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)' ) $($line<checkcon.sh)" >> somefile.txt"
the output is :eth: inet 222.22.22.22 .
I need output : BHHHHH7 eth:    inet 22.22.222.22

Comment: @MaxBoyar sorry I don't see what you are doing wrong. For me it is the 2nd bit that is not working, because I don't have an executable called `k-opp-` or a file `checkcon.sh`. I am thinking that I have miss-read what your inputs are, can you make them clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have pairs of lines, why not join them with a `sed`-one-liner?

Just pipe your output through...

```bash
sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'
```

Thus changing your original script to:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
file=list.txt
cat "$file" | while read line
do
  echo $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)'
  $line <checkcon.sh # This line can not possibly work...
done | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' >>somefile.txt
```

This will produce some failures, though, due to a line in your original script that can not work:

```bash
me@home:~$ ./script.sh                                                                    
./script.sh: 6: ./script.sh: cannot open checkcon.sh: No such file                        
./script.sh: 6: ./script.sh: k-opp-: not found                                            
./script.sh: 6: ./script.sh: cannot open checkcon.sh: No such file                        
./script.sh: 6: ./script.sh: k-opp-: not found                                            
./script.sh: 6: ./script.sh: cannot open checkcon.sh: No such file                        
./script.sh: 6: ./script.sh: k-opp-: not found                                            
me@home:~$ cat somefile.txt 
 BHHHHH7   BHHHHH8 
 BHHHHH9
```

You should probably pass `$line` as an argument to `checkcon.sh`: `checkcon.sh "$line"`.

And of course, the output of `checkcon.sh` is missing here as well.

With a dummy `checkcon.sh` that produces output on stdout, things work as expected:

```bash
me@home:~$ ./script.sh
me@home:~$ cat somefile.txt 
 BHHHHH7  eth:    inet 22.22.222.22
 BHHHHH8  eth:    inet 222.22.22.22
 BHHHHH9  eth:    inet 222.222.22.222
```

Comment: after runing that script ,somefile.txt is empty

Comment: Hm... `$line <checkcon.sh` from the script you posted can not work.  Should that be `checkcon.sh host-you-grepped-from-file` instead?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `echo -n $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)' >>somefile.txt` (I added the -n option, it should remove the trailing newline character that the echo command appends at the end of the string).

Comment: My `grep` takes care and outputs properly terminated lines anyway.

Comment: You can try to follow the indication of this StackOverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249755/how-to-prevent-grep-from-printing-a-trailing-newline which uses the `tr` command to terminate a line where the first newline is found

Comment: My point is your answer by itself is not a solution.

Comment: this line : echo -n $line |grep -o -P '(?<=-a).*(?=-d)' >>somefile.txt
stucks the script :(

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I should have put my idea as a comment. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @LuxGiammi: You can still do.